# debug logs is not printing in console and log file is not generating

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

Hi I am new to Log4j help me to fix this issue.

One of the module of my application previously used spring boot default common loggers, but now I am implementing log4j to this module

I am facing issue like if I add log statement with debug logs it does not get printed in console and log file is not generating.

POM.XML:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration strict="true" name="XMLConfig">
    <Appenders>
        <Appender type="Console" name="STDOUT">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout">
                 <Pattern>%d{[MM.dd.yyyy] | [HH:mm:ss]|}%level{FATAL=[FATAL],ERROR=[ERROR], WARN=[WARN], INFO=[INFO], DEBUG=[DEBUG],  TRACE=[TRACE]}|[%X{sessionID}]|[%F]|[%M]|[%L]|%m%throwable%n</Pattern>
            </Layout>
        </Appender>
     
      <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/data/storage/log/Test.log" filePattern="/data/storage/log/test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.Logs.gz">
    
        
            <Layout type="PatternLayout">
                 <Pattern>%d{[MM.dd.yyyy] | [HH:mm:ss]|}%level{FATAL=[FATAL],ERROR=[ERROR], WARN=[WARN], INFO=[INFO], DEBUG=[DEBUG],  TRACE=[TRACE]}|[%X{sessionID}]|[%F]|[%M]|[%L]|%m%throwable%n</Pattern>
            </Layout>
            
        </RollingFile>       
    </Appenders>
    
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="com.test" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/> 
        </logger>
        
        <Root level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My CLass:

```
Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

LOGGER.debug("DEBUG LOGS");
```

Answer (score -1):

basically

`level = ERROR`

means that only log entries with level `ERROR` or higher (more specific) will be handled by that logger or filter. `DEBUG` is a lower level. Change level to `DEBUG` (or `ALL`) in configuration for both Loggers (or, just for testing, call `LOGGER.error("now a test ERROR");`

Documentation for [Level](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Level.html):

> Levels used for identifying the severity of an event. Levels are organized from most specific to least:
>
> ```
> OFF (most specific, no logging)
> FATAL (most specific, little data)
> ERROR
> WARN
> INFO
> DEBUG
> TRACE (least specific, a lot of data)
> ALL (least specific, all data)
> ```
>
> Typically, configuring a level in a filter or on a logger will cause logging events of that level and those that are more specific to pass through the filter. A special level, ALL, is guaranteed to capture all levels when used in logging configurations.